# Auto insert comments when I press “o” or “O" in normal mode

Tags: vim

I found this command in a Stack Overflow post:

```
:set formatoptions+=r
```

This works great in insert mode, but in normal mode pressing <kbd>o</kbd> doesn't really work for multiline comments, ie:

```
/**
 *
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the comment leader to be included:

`:set formatoptions+=o`

Otherwise:

`:set formatoptions-=o`